# Why does Word want to convert my rtf-file and if I do convert, it doesn't format my text

Tags: formatting, rtf, linebreaks, filemaker

I have the following rtf-file

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}
test
}
```

When I try to open it in Word, I get prompted to convert it. If I do so, it opens the file and displays the content above, not just the word "test" in Courier.

Any clues?

UPDATE:
I am generating my rtf-file from Filemaker. This seems to be adding trouble. I have now changed some things, so that I get a file with CR-LF linebreaks, which is also in utf-8 format. I hoped that that would solve the problem. Now, however, when I have a file like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}[CR][LF]
test[CR][LF]
test2[CR][LF]
}[CR][LF]
```

[CR] and [LF] are just to illustrate I am using CR-LF line breaks (seen when opening in good old Notepad++).

[image]

I get the following in Word:

> testtest2

Where did the linebreaks go?

Comment: Word 2019 displays it perfectly well.

Comment: It seems to be a Mac-Windows issue... I have created the text file from FileMaker Pro. Filemaker is Mac oriented. So I think it has to do with the type of line-breaks... Working on it...

Comment: I can open it, though it is not showing any line breaks! Even (for the Filemaker people around) if I use 'char(13) & char(10)' as line  breaks. Also, the document is now utf-8 coded!